# ASP.NET, PayPal Sandbox Error After Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal-sandbox

I'm following along with a tutorial from the official ASP.NET website, and I'm getting the following error after entering my PayPal Sandbox mock buyer account: "We are unable to validate your information." "At this time, we are unable to process your request."

[image]

I'm very new to ASP.NET and Web Dev, but I'm comfortable with C#. As you can see there's no error code, so I'm not sure what's gone wrong.

Running tutorial out of Firefox 29.01, using Visual Studio 2013 Professional RC 2, Windows 7 32-bit, ASP.NET 4.5, on Localhost. I'm logged into my PayPal developer account in another tab. The mock buyer email/password is correct. Localhost port is correct.

I'm on step 11, of this tutorial page:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal

The calling code to PayPal is:

```
public bool ShortcutExpressCheckout(string amt, ref string token, ref string retMsg)
{
    if (bSandbox)
    {
        pEndPointURL = pEndPointURL_SB;
        host = host_SB;
    }

    string returnURL = "http://localhost:9038/Checkout/CheckoutReview.aspx";
    string cancelURL = "http://localhost:9038/Checkout/CheckoutCancel.aspx";

    NVPCodec encoder = new NVPCodec();
    encoder["METHOD"] = "SetExpressCheckout";
    encoder["RETURNURL"] = returnURL;
    encoder["CANCELURL"] = cancelURL;
    encoder["BRANDNAME"] = "Wingtip Toys Sample Application";
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"] = amt;
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"] = amt;
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"] = "Sale";
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"] = "USD";

    //Get the Shopping Cart Products.
    using (ShoppingCartActions myCartOrders = new ShoppingCartActions())
    {
        List<CartItem> myOrderList = myCartOrders.GetCartItems();

        for (int i = 0; i < myOrderList.Count; i++)
        {
            encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME" + i] = myOrderList[i].Product.ProductName.ToString();
            encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" + i] = myOrderList[i].Product.UnitPrice.ToString();
            encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY" + i] = myOrderList[i].Quantity.ToString();
        }

        string pStrrequestforNvp = encoder.Encode();
        string pStrresponsenvp = HttpCall(pStrrequestforNvp);

        NVPCodec decoder = new NVPCodec();
        decoder.Decode(pStrresponsenvp);

        string strAck = decoder["ACK"].ToLower();
        if (strAck != null && (strAck == SUCCESS || strAck == SUCCESSWITHWARNING))
        {
            token = decoder["TOKEN"];
            string ECURL = "https://" + host + "/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout" + "&token=" + token;
            retMsg = ECURL;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            retMsg = "ErrorCode=" + decoder["L_ERRORCODE0"] + "&" +
                "Desc=" + decoder["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"] + "&" +
                "Desc2=" + decoder["L_LONGMESSAGE0"];
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion to try would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that you replaced the API information in your code with your API values? `public string APIUsername = "<Your API Username>";`  `private string APIPassword = "<Your API Password>";` `private string APISignature = "<Your Signature>";`

Comment: Yes, the APIUsername, APIPassword, and APISignature variables are all populated with my sandbox Business account API Credentials.

Comment: I've been getting this response too since yesterday. I opened a ticket with Paypal support, and they replied that it's a known issue they are working on it. No ETA on solution. Our release is on hold because of this - Paypal, as usual, delivers exceptional service.